# How to pass user back to front end client after authorizing and obtaining access token?

Tags: django, reactjs, redux, django-rest-framework, spotify

I have a Django backend and React/Redux front end and I am trying to integrate the Spotify API. I am a total django noob so please have mercy. I currently send the user to my backend via a regular ol' anchor tag on the front end. My backend then redirects the user to the Spotify Authorize page and then that page redirects them to another page which trades the authorization code for the access token which I now have. However this code and the urls just send me to my backend API. How do I get the user back to the front end with this access token? "My" code:

```
from django.views.generic.base import RedirectView, TemplateView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import generics, viewsets, permissions
from django.urls import reverse
from furl import furl
import requests


def build_authorize_url(request):
    params = {
        "client_id": "<client-id>",
        "response_type": "code",
        "redirect_uri": request.build_absolute_uri(
            reverse("spotify callback")
        ),
        "scope": " ".join(
            [
                'user-read-currently-playing',
                'user-modify-playback-state',
                'user-read-playback-state',
                'streaming',
                'app-remote-control',
                'playlist-read-collaborative',
                'playlist-modify-public',
                'playlist-read-private',
                'playlist-modify-private',
                'user-library-modify',
                'user-top-read',
                'user-read-playback-position',
                'user-read-recently-played',
            ]
        ),
    }
    print(params)

    url = (
        furl("https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize")
        .add(params)
        .url
    )
    print(url)

    return url


AUTH_HEADER = {
    "Authorization": "Basic "
    + base64.b64encode(
        "<my client id>:<my client secret>".encode()
    ).decode()
}


def handle_callback(request):
    code = request.GET["code"]

    response = requests.post(
        "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token",
        data={
            "grant_type": "authorization_code",
            "code": code,
            "redirect_uri": request.build_absolute_uri(
                reverse("spotify callback")
            ),
        },
        headers=AUTH_HEADER,
    )

    return response.json()


class SpotifyLoginView(RedirectView):
    query_string = True

    def get_redirect_url(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return build_authorize_url(self.request)


class SpotifyCallbackView(generics.GenericAPIView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print(handle_callback(request))

        return Response(handle_callback(request))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After getting the access/refresh token you can redirect the user to your frontend URL passing the token values like in [this official example](https://github.com/spotify/web-api-auth-examples/blob/master/authorization_code/app.js#L107) from Spotify's Github account (written in JS but the idea is the same):

```js
res.redirect('/#' +
  querystring.stringify({
    access_token: access_token,
    refresh_token: refresh_token
  })
);
```

You can read more about the authentication flows [here](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/#authorization-code-flow).

Comment: But that sends the tokens along in the url does it not? I would like to just pass them along as a json response and then save them in local storage.

Comment: Yes, it sends the tokens in the url. But in your frontend, you can get them from the url and store them in local storage.

Comment: I am going to do that, it just seems hacky. Also, how would I handle refreshing the token? It seems like I need to send the user back to the server for a similar flow as the original auth code instead using it with a refresh token. However, in similar real world situations the user does not know the token is being refreshed. How does that happen?

Comment: @Morks You can handle this in the frontend side. If you get a 401 status in the response you send a new request and try to refresh the token. Then you make the request again with the new token.

Comment: According to the spotify API site, the refresh flow is the same as the token flow with the only difference being that the refresh token is used in place of the authorization code. That is also to say that the headers will need to contain the clientId and client secret in the POST request for the token, which is the reason that the request needed to be performed from the back end as to not expose the client secret. How is it possible that it can be done from the front end without exposing the client secret?

Comment: It's not. The client secret should be stored only in your backend. From the front end, you make a request to your backend, your backend makes a request to Spotify requesting a new access token, and then your back end returns the new token to the front-end.

Comment: This gives me cors errors, been trying to handle but no luck- you wouldn't have any idea how I could fix would you?